# Those are rookie numbers in this racket - what does "in this racket" mean?

Tags: meaning

From the movie *The Wolf of Wall Street*:

> Do you jerk off?
>   Do I... Do I jerk off? Yeah. Yeah, I jerk off. Yeah.
>   How many times a week?
>   Like three or four. Three or four times, maybe five.
>   Gotta pump those numbers up. Those are rookie numbers in this **racket**. I myself, I jerk off at least twice a day.

What does the guy mean by **in this racket**?

Comment: Have you consulted a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/racket) for the meaning of *racket*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Racket as in protection racket (organized crime). Here it is used jokingly to mean any sort of business or activity. I guess it's a kind of synecdoche and it probably originated in the US in 1930's.